# How can you calculate the average of something cyclic like "hour of the day"?

Tags: python, math

Say I have a dataset of page visits derived from log data - with user ID and time visited.

Now, if I wanted to find the average time visited for each user, I might try calculating the mean "hour" - but there's a problem. If a user tends to visit around midnight, and we log 3 visits... 23:00, 0:00, and 1:00, our average "hour" will be 8, representing 8:00. If we only logged 2 visits, 23:00 and 1:00, the average hour would be 12, representing 12:00 midday. Clearly, the true average for both of these users is 0:00 midnight. I guess the issue boils down to the fact that midnight is both "24" and "0" simultaneously.

It occurred to me that perhaps the ideal solution can be found by using a number system with base 12?

Anyway, I have no doubt that someone must have solved this problem before - so can anyone provide any pointers on where I could find more? Here's a basic reprex in python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"User":[0,0,1,1,1],"Hour Visited":[23,1,23,0,1]})
df.groupby("User").mean()

>       Hour Visited
> User  
> 0     12.0
> 1     8.0
```

Comment: You can use e.g. trig https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Mean_time_of_day